# Can I recover my code from Spyder console even if the .py file no longer exists?

Tags: python, spyder

So I mistakenly overwrote a .py file. I had run the original version of the file in the Spyder console yesterday and to my surprise, the console runs the original script when I give it the command to run the file with the file name even though the .py file does not have the code anymore. Is there any way I can get the console to show me the code that it's running? Or any other way to recover the file?

Thanks

Comment: maybe it runs `.pyc` with `byte-code`. There are tools to convert back `byte-code` to `python code` but it will be not ideal.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If you know the names of the functions your file contained, you can run in the console `myfunction??` to get the source code of the function `myfunction`, for instance. I think that's your best chance to recover your code.